# How to add condition for process buttons on Recognize Input VAT TX503500

Tags: acumatica

I have to add a description field that is mandatory, so that the action of processing can be carried out, however I am a little confused, due to the fact that the field is in the filter area, to be copied later in the descriptions to be processed.

How can I customize the actions Process, ProcessAll?

I don't find these actions in Override Methods

thanks for helping me, I'm really new to this

sorry if my english is not so good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the Process/Process All actions are mapped to one method which is using the SetProcessDelegate method of the processing data view.
What you need to do is for first locating to the Graph(ProcessInputSVAT) of the Recognize Input VAT screen(TX503500). After opening the source code for that graph you can see that it's derived from the ProcessSVATBase class. And when you'll enter that class you'll see the mentioned SetProcessDelegate function called by Data View:

```
    protected virtual void SVATTaxFilter_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        SVATTaxFilter filter = (SVATTaxFilter)e.Row;
        if (filter == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        this.SVATDocuments.SetProcessDelegate(delegate(List<SVATConversionHistExt> list)
        {
            ProcessSVATBase.ProcessPendingVATProc(list, filter);
        });
    }
```

So we've figured out which graph extension we should create. Now, it's necessary to override the RowSelected event of the SVATTaxFilter DAC in the extension graph.

```
public class ProcessSVATBaseExt : PXGraphExtension<ProcessSVATBase>
{
    public virtual void SVATTaxFilter_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        SVATTaxFilter filter = e.Row as SVATTaxFilter;
        if (filter != null)
        {
            Base.SVATDocuments.SetProcessDelegate(delegate (List<SVATConversionHistExt> list)
            {
                // Here you can manage the list items and then call the base method
                // ...
                ProcessSVATBase.ProcessPendingVATProc(list, filter); // the base method
                // Here you can manage the list items after the base method
                // ...
            });
        }
    }
}
```